# How do i modify the codes so that in the method getProductTransaction, I return a list of transactions instead of a single transaction

Tags: c#

```
protected void bind()
{
        Session["name"] = "John";
        string name = Session["name"].ToString();
        List<TransactionDetail> transList = new List<TransactionDetail>();
        transList.Add(aTrans.getProductTransaction(name));

        gv_Transaction.DataSource = transList;
        gv_Transaction.DataBind();
}

public TransactionDetail getProductTransaction(string p_UserName)
{
        TransactionDetail prodDetail = null;
        string tran_ID, offer_ID, user, Prod_Image, prod_Name;
        decimal prod_Price;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        string queryStr = "SELECT * FROM TransactionDetail WHERE UserName = @user";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", p_UserName);

        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            tran_ID = dr["TransactionID"].ToString();
            offer_ID = dr["OfferId"].ToString();
            user = dr["UserName"].ToString();
            Prod_Image = dr["Image"].ToString();
            prod_Name = dr["ProductName"].ToString();
            prod_Price = decimal.Parse(dr["ProductPrice"].ToString());
            prodDetail = new TransactionDetail(tran_ID, offer_ID, user, Prod_Image, prod_Name, prod_Price);
        }
        else
        {
            prodDetail = null;
        }

        conn.Close();
        dr.Close();
        dr.Dispose();

        return prodDetail;
}
```

The output only returns a single transaction instead of everything. The code is trying to retrieve all the transaction history from John but now it is only returning one transaction history. Is it because need to change it to arraylist instead so that it has multiple transactions. So I change both the aspx.cs bind method and `getProductTransaction`

Comment: use a loop.... with reading each time.

Answer (score 3):

Change `if(dr.Read())` to `while(dr.Read())` (you're looping until `Read()` is false)

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You also need a `List<TransactionDetail>` to add to on every loop and change the return type to `IList<TransactionDetail>` and return the list instead of the single object.

Edit: something like this should work...

```
protected void bind()
{
    var name = "John";
    Session["name"] = name;
    gv_Transaction.DataSource = getProductTransactions(name);
    gv_Transaction.DataBind();
}

public IList<TransactionDetail> getProductTransactions(string p_UserName)
{
    var transList = new List<TransactionDetail>();
    var queryStr = "SELECT * FROM TransactionDetail WHERE UserName = @user";

    string tran_ID, offer_ID, user, Prod_Image, prod_Name;
    decimal prod_Price;

    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", p_UserName);
        conn.Open();
        using(var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                tran_ID = dr["TransactionID"].ToString();
                offer_ID = dr["OfferId"].ToString();
                user = dr["UserName"].ToString();
                Prod_Image = dr["Image"].ToString();
                prod_Name = dr["ProductName"].ToString();
                prod_Price = decimal.Parse(dr["ProductPrice"].ToString());
                transList.Add(new TransactionDetail(tran_ID, offer_ID, user, Prod_Image, prod_Name, prod_Price));
            }
        }
    }
    return transList;
}
```

Comment: how do i return at the last part of the method getProductTransaction? @Rush Frisby

Comment: Additionally, I'd strongly recommend putting the `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` into `using (.....) { .... }` blocks to ensure proper disposal at the end of their usage